# XMLHttpRequest does not work in a Chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, gopro

I am new to XMLHttpRequest and JavaScript and all this stuff.
I made a gopro WiFi app to control gopro cameras with XMLHttpRequest, but it does not work with the packaged Chrome app, it works with the HTML file in Chrome.
[Source](https://github.com/KonradIT/HeroProApp/tree/gh-pages/Chrome)
Any ideas?

Comment: Be specific if you want help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is using inline scripting (e.g. `<button onclick="command('bacpac','PW','%00')">`)

This is [disallowed](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy#what) by Chrome's Content Security Policy for apps/extensions, and you cannot override this.

You'll have to purge your `index.html` of all inline code and add handlers (or indeed, buttons) from a script. [Example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) in the Chrome docs.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're not using XHR (XMLHttpRequest) (at least I can't find any usage of it in your code), instead you're trying to dynamically create  tags with remote url's as src. Loading remote scripts in  tags is not allowed in the apps CSP.

So the way to fix this, is to actually use XHR.

Comment: Here is the xml http request javascript code: https://github.com/KonradIT/HeroProApp/blob/gh-pages/Chrome/src/heropro.js  and here is the index.html: https://github.com/KonradIT/HeroProApp/blob/gh-pages/Chrome/src/index.html i have done [this](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) already.